# Compile cpp to a 32 bit dll file

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mingw, 32-bit

How do I compile my CPP file into a 32 bit DLL file under **Windows** with MinGW?
Well I researched for a while now of how to compile CPP file into a 32 bit DLL file but all I found was converting 32 Bit DLL into a 64 bit which does not answer my question

Comment: [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) provides a 32-bit MinGW, among other things.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the option `--enable-lib32` when compiling according to MinGW's [document](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Compiling%20the%20Runtime/).

Comment: That flag can be used when compiling MinGW itself, not when compiling something using it.